# Edit an Mediawiki page in MySQL

Tags: mediawiki

Why doesn't the edit Text in the MySQL table text show in the Article page?
You can only see it if you edit the Article, then the you see the in mySQL edited text.

Does exist an second table with the article text?

Answer (score 1):

You should never ever edit a revision's text directly in the database to avoid any data corruption and to have a revision of every page version/edit. The [`text` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table) itself holds only the wikitext of a specific revision/page, not the parsed text. If you request a page, MediaWiki parses the wikitext to html and saves the result in the parser cache (parsing is an expensive task, so it would be very bad for performance to parse every page on every page view). If you request the page a second time, the content will be requested from parser cache, instead of reparsing the wikitext from the text table.

That's why you have to clear the parser cache, if you change the wikitext on another way as the MediaWiki interface (if you edit a page in the interface, MediaWiki itself triggers a reparse of the page ;)). You could do that with the URL parameter "action=purge" next time :)

Comment: Even purge (or deleting the HTML cache) will not update link tables (such as the list of templates used on the page). An changing the text in the DB will cause the text and the hash to mismatch and who knows what else. It is a thoroughly bad idea.

Comment: "It is a thoroughly bad idea." What i've said :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the data is in the table objectcache saved, you only have to delete the content and it works.